# Forward all IPv6 traffic from a specific port to an other server

Tags: ipv6, redirection

This sounds like a frequently answered question, but probably I used the wrong search terms.

I have two independent Linux servers `A` and `B`. I moved an application (rsync), which uses TCP Port 4444 for the rsync protocoll, from `A` to `B`. Unfortunately some users still use `A` to access the application. Is it possible, and how, to automagically forward the traffic to `B`?

Both servers use IPv6, and only the traffic incoming on port 4444 shall be redirected.

Comment: What kind of traffic? HTTP? Raw TCP? Some other protocol?

Comment: I should have mentioned this: it's rsync. (TCP

Comment: While you're at it: switch users to a DNS name, then the IP behind it can be replaced at any time.

Comment: What's the network topology, roughly? Are both servers behind the same gateway that you control? (Either IP-level NAT or TCP-level proxying might be the answer here depending on the network layout and on what kind of performance you want.)

Comment: `A` and `B` are independent servers from different providers, not at all connected on Ethernet level. They do not share a common interface to a router.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple: `rinetd`

Debian (Ubuntu, Mint, …) already contains an actual version of this package. It works with IPv4 and IPv6. The configuration in `/etc/rinetd.conf` is as straight forward as one would think:

```
#IP rinetd    Src-Port  Dest-IP       Dest-Port
10.0.0.234      23      10.0.0.254      23
10.0.0.234      222     10.1.0.254      22
10.0.0.234      80      example.org     80
2001:db8::3     100     fd00:abcd::1    23
…
```